# Android layout : trying to add an edittext above a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add an edittext above a listview. The edittext field gets displayed, however, it is repeated for each row in the listview as well, which I don't want.

I have tried placing it outside the first inner LinearLayout but there is no difference in the behaviour.

Can someone please help me to figure out what I might be doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchString"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_holo_light"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Search for..."
            android:text="" >
        </EditText>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="3sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingRight="1sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvCategory"
                android:paddingRight="1sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
                android:paddingRight="1sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="1sp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/idAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It sounds like you have an EditText in the view hierarchy for you ListView items, which are you not showing here.

Comment: This is the xml which is giving me the issues. There is nothing else missing.

Comment: ...except the child views that populate the ListView.  Unless I misunderstand your question, you're wondering why there is an EditText in each row of the ListView.

Comment: The only thing that gets populated is the textviews which are defined in the relativelayout.

Comment: "The edittext field gets displayed, however, it is repeated for each row in the listview as well."  What does this mean? Do you not want this repetition in the ListView rows?

Comment: @DougStevenson That's correct. I don't want the repetition.

Comment: show us the *list item* layout xml

Comment: @muratgu 
There is no other xml

Comment: then what do you do to add items to your list? do you use a list adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the edit text as header view to the list.

public void addHeaderView (View v)

Ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)